# Submitting a form using jquery doesn't submit it as remote: true rails 4.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have to submit a form when user clicks a button for that I'm using an onclick JS function call on that button.

In that function, I simply submit the form I want using `.submit()` function.

JS function I use,

```
$('#form_id').submit()
```

Also in the `form_tag` I've used `:remote=>true`. The HTML method has been changed to post using `:method=> "post"`.

Controller also has proper `respond_to` block with `format.js` block.

View file has proper `.js.erb` file.

But whenever I click the button it is being processed as HTML. If I manually click on that form's submit button it's processed as JS successfully.

How to fix the issue??

Answer (score 4):

```
form = document.querySelector('#form_id');
form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', {bubbles: true})); // you can specify more options in `Event()` for reliability across different browsers.
```

or

```
form = document.querySelector('#form_id');
Rails.fire(form, 'submit');
```

Found answer [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29546)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jquery `submit` (or pure javascript `submit`), you need to use `requestSubmit` instead

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

This describes the difference between `submit` (which jQuery uses) and `requestSubmit` (which you need to use to get rails remote forms working via javascript submission)

Answer (score -4):

**What is remote => true?**

If you specify :remote => true in your form during generation that means forms is submitted remotely.

**So what about form.submit() ?**

There is no necessary to use jQuery code to submit. Your app understands that form has to be submitted remotely.

**I hope it helps**