# Rails 6: SimpleFrom Remote: true submit via javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-ujs

I have read this [submit a rails remote form with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570824/submit-a-rails-remote-form-with-javascript)

and none of the solutions seem to work. I just need to run a callback before the submit gets called.

#### View

```html
<form id="formA" " novalidate="novalidate" action="https://www.demo.com/form.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post" _lpchecked="1">
...
</form>
```

#### JS

```
var form = document.forms.item(0)

form.addEventListener('submit', async function(e) {
   e.stopImmediatePropagation()
   e.preventDefault();
   ...
   form.submit()
});
```

My form does not seem to submit with remote: true, so no ajax, I get a html response instead of a js response.

Comment: Can your issue be solved with one of the [custom events](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#rails-ujs-event-handlers) fired by Rails? For example `form.addEventListener("ajax:before", function (event) => { ... })`

Comment: Good recommendation, but what happened when I have a form that is remote: false?

Comment: Then the `"ajax:before"` event does not fire. Since [a remote check is made beforehand](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f4c51e8660bf1771268d45325fff8378eb90698e/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/features/remote.coffee#L19-L20).

Comment: My form needs to work both ways, depending on situation.  I need to run the call back in both situations remote:true and remote: false.

Comment: In that case you could attach the event like you currently already do. Events bubble from the target upwards in the DOM tree, [the Rails event is attached to the `document`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f4c51e8660bf1771268d45325fff8378eb90698e/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/start.coffee#L58). Removing the `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` call will let the event bubble further upwards, eventually reaching the Rails handler. You could also omit `e.preventDefault()` since that is done by the Rails handler if the form is remote.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Could you post a example of the code?

Comment: I'm basically saying that if you remove `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` and  `e.preventDefault()` the event will reach the Rails handler after your event is handled, so just `form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) { ... })` (without `stopImmediatePropagation`, `preventDefault` and `submit`). This will handle your event, then when finished Rails handles the ajax stuff.

Comment: My call back method I am using is async, so the form submits before the async is done.  Any solution?

Comment: In that case replace `form.submit()` with `Rails.handleRemote.call(this, e)` to manually pass the event to the Rails handler.

Comment: Thank you I will try, will that work for the remote: false situation too?

Comment: My bad, the `handleRemote` function should be called as `Rails.handleRemote.call(e.target, e)`. Since [`handleRemote`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f4c51e8660bf1771268d45325fff8378eb90698e/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/features/remote.coffee#L16-L72) expects `this` to be the `event.target`.

Comment: It does not handle `remote: false`, for that you'll have to make the [remote check](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f4c51e8660bf1771268d45325fff8378eb90698e/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/features/remote.coffee#L11-L13) yourself. Eg. `if (e.target.hasAttribute("data-remote") && e.target.getAttribute("data-remote") != "false") { Rails.handleRemote.call(e.target, e) } else { form.submit() }` You might also want to disable the submit-button while your async stuff is being processed, to prevent the user from sending multiple "submit" events.

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late to answer, but I solved same issue with this code.

```
form = document.querySelector('#form_id');
form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', {bubbles: true})); // you can specify more options in `Event()` for reliability across different browsers.
```

It is from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52304806/1529453